# what's the meaning of the function parameter declaration?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have see this in the http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function

```
int f(int a, int *p, int (*(*x)(double))[3]);
```

what's the meaning of `int (*(*x)(double))[3]`?

Comment: [cdecl](http://cdecl.org) to the rescue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(*x)` ensure `x` is a pointer then `(*x)(double)` will give us a function pointer whose parameter is a double and the next is `(*(*x)(double))` which means the function will return a pointer `p` and `p` is depicted by `int int (*p)[3]` which in the end gives us a pointer pointing to an array of `int[3]`

So all in all, what we have here is a pointer pointing to a function whose single parameter is a double and the function returns a pointer pointing to an array of int[3].

Here is a simple example to demonstrate it, hope it can be helpful.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef int int3[3];
int arr3[3]{1, 2, 3};

int3 * get3Int(double x){
    int (*arr)[3] = &arr3;
    return arr;
}

int testFunctionPointer(int (*(*x)(double))[3]){
    int (*arr)[3] = x(1.0);
    for(auto n: *arr)
        cout<<n<<endl;
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    testFunctionPointer(get3Int);
    return 0;
}
```